# python requests - file upload not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having a heck of a time getting this to work. The form code...

```
<div bran="uplo">
    <form name="uplo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.aspx">
        <input type="hidden" name="proc" value="wagr"/>
        <span>Data File:</span>
        <span>
            <input type="file" name="wagr"/>
        </span>
    </form>
        <span>
            <button onclick="document.uplo.submit();">Upload</button>
        </span>
</div>
```

Here's the 356th version of the code I've tried...

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/upload.aspx'
files = {'file':('data.txt', open('data.txt', 'rb'))}
data = {'proc':'wagr'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

All that seems to happen when I look at `r.content` is the page itself and that is all.

I asked for permission here is the actual form...

https://dfu.xb-online.com/wagerupload/betupload.aspx

Comment: Instead of `open('data.txt')` can you provide full path to file `/home/user/dir/file`

Comment: What was the 355th version?

Comment: @MaheshKaria In this case the file I'm trying to upload is right alongside the python script but I even tried directly going to it and still now luck.

Comment: @Shadow lol... I'm an amateur at this stuff so I've been trying all sorts of variations and have gotten nowhere. 356 was a little hyperbole, but just a little.

Comment: There is a mismatch between the form and the Python snippet. In the form, the name of the file input is "wagr" while in the Python snippet the name is "file". Could this be it?

Comment: @tom I think it should be.

Comment: @tom I posted the actual form... I wasn't sure if it was allowed so I attempted to cover up the details. Turns out, it's fine.

Comment: The form you linked also calls the file input "wagr", so try changing `'file'` to `'wagr'` in the Python script. As Sraw mentioned in his answer, you should check what the response is supposed to look like so you can tell if the script is working. All major web browsers have built-in developer tools that can monitor network requests, so submit the form using your favourite browser with the network monitor open and inspect the response that the browser receives.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your post.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJQcvwSzBape4lDoO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="proc"

wagr
------WebKitFormBoundaryJQcvwSzBape4lDoO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wagr"; filename="test.py"
Content-Type: text/x-python


------WebKitFormBoundaryJQcvwSzBape4lDoO--
```

This is mine, you can see, `name` for file should be `wagr`.

Second, check your response.

Actually, it will return a page but contains more information based on the file you uploaded.